# The display contrast on my new iMac (the Retina 4k 21.5" model) is too high. Can it be lowered past the lowest setting?

Tags: display, imac, macos

Just looking at my new iMac was giving me a headache: the "Retina" display was so high-contrast, even at the lowest contrast setting, that it was searing *my* retinas.

Is there a way to reduce the contrast past the lowest keyboard setting?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - by using display profiles, you can alter what absolute values the relative 100% and 0% contrast settings are. You don’t even need calibration hardware, but sometimes that helps you dial this in precisely.

- Go to the "Color" tab of the "Display" panel of System Preferences
- Select the display profiles, one by one to see which you prefer.

When I got to "SMPTE RP 431-2-2007-DCI (P3)," I hit PAYDIRT: contrast and saturation were down to something I could easily live with.

Comment: If you really wanted to contribute, why didn't you simply add either (a) your own version of the answer as a separate answer, or (b) add comments, rather than altering my own answer almost beyond recognition?